# Independent button

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code that creates buttons OnLoad with the attributes being the values from an ASP page that fetches from the database. But whatever event I want each button to do, all the other buttons do it and it executes before the buttons are displayed. Please help...

```
function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
return '\n<input'
                + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
                + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
                + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
                + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
                + (onClick ? ' onclick=\''+ onClick + '\'':'')
                + '>';

}


function DisplayButtons(cableData) {

var newContent = '';

$.each(cableData, function (i, item) {

newContent += createButtons(item.CommonCable, null, "submit",       item.CommonCable,alert("clicked"));

});

$('#Categories').html(newContent);
```

}

Comment: its horrible to see a lot of CAPITAL LETTRERS!! please edit it to make it human readable

Comment: SO should provide a `.toLowerCase()` feature soon for the edits.

Comment: i just want to be able to use each button independently after the buttons are displayed....

Comment: @ACB now that it is in proper casing, please help...

Answer (score 0):

Do not call "alert('clicked')" (or whatever action you want to execute when your button is clicked) in the function call that creates the button, or it will be executed right away. Instead, create an anonymous function and wrap the call in it. E.g.

```
newContent += createButtons(item.CommonCable, null, "submit",       item.CommonCable,"alert('clicked')");
```

**edit:** didn't notice you build the button as html text. In this case simply pass the code you want to execute (function call) as text. Edited the code above to reflect this.

Comment: thank you, now the buttons are displayed and the event is not executed simultaneously. But i get an error from my aspx page:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: i have now put this code and it does not alert, when should i call the anonymous function?                                                                                                                                                                             newContent += createButtons(item.CommonCable, null, "submit", item.CommonCable, function () { alert("clicked") });

Comment: thanx man , finally it's working. i had to play around with the quotes